# How do I use tesseract OCR?

Tags: php, tesseract

I follow the instructions, but I only get a blank page.

```
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
    echo (new TesseractOCR("imagen.jpeg"))->run();
```

I tried defining the location of tesseract doing it, but it still doesn't work.

```
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
    echo (new TesseractOCR("imagen.jpeg"))->executable('C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe')->run();
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Have a look at your error logs to make sure it's actually finding the files

Comment: "C:/Program" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: "C:/Program"  Is not recognized as an internal or external command, program, or executable batch file. (Translated by google).

Comment: I think it´s a problem with white spaces in the path but how can i 
Replace them

Comment: i solved moving tesseract installation thanks.